# On QT Creator TableWidget, how to add a row by presssing enter or tab key?

Tags: qt-creator

I want the user is able to add a line on a QTableWidget, if the cursor is at last field of the last line and tab or enter key are pressed - like in Libreoffice Base or MS Access, for example.
Possible to do it on widget visual property editor, or should I use some code?